# How to get Dates In ZIG-ZAG format in javascript using datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i need dates in datepicker like below pattern using Zig-Zag flow in Javascript Datepicker

2014-11-10 - 2014-11-15
2014-11-16 - 2014-11-17
2014-11-18 - 2014-11-18

Comment: which datepicker exactly? There's no single "JavaScript datepicker"..there are dozens, if not hundreds of plugins. And what is "zig-zag flow" when it's at home? I see some dates in YYYY-MM-DD format, that's all. And lastly what have you tried? Check the documentation for your datepicker, it should be trivial to change the format. Your question is too vague and unclear for us to know what your problem really is.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't specified any specific JS-Library, I'm assuming you're referring to the HTML5 Standard `<input type="date">`, which renders a datepicker depending on the browser currently used.

The format of this datepicker shown to the user is determined by the locale of the users browser, whereas the value retrieved using JavaScript is always in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

```js
const dateNode = document.querySelector("input[type=date]")

dateNode.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(`Current JS-Value: ${event.target.value}, which is of type ${typeof event.target.value}`)
})
```

```html
<label>Enter date:
<input type="date">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i worked around on this soltuion.

```
 function remove(tr_id){         
     $("#tr_"+tr_id).remove();    
     counter = $("#counter").val();          
     counter = parseInt( counter ) - 1 ; 
     $("#counter").val(counter);  
}
function AddNewElement(){
    counter = $("#counter").val();          
    counter = parseInt( counter ) + 1 ; 
    // YOUR SPECIFIC DYNAMIC HTML
    var elestr = '<tr id="tr_'+counter+'" class="ele_tr"><td><input onclick="remove('+counter+');" id="remove" type="button" value="Remove"></td></tr>';
     $("#ele_list").append(elestr);    
     $("#counter").val(counter);  
}

$('body').on('focus',".dp_start", function(){
    counter = $(this).data('counter');
    counter = parseInt(counter);

    var trialDate = new Date ($("#enddate_"+ (counter-1)).val());
        trialDate.setDate ( trialDate.getDate () + 1 );

    $(this).datepicker({
           // changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate:  trialDate, 
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#enddate_"+counter).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });            
});

$('body').on('focus',".dp_end", function(){
    counter = $(this).data('counter');
    counter = parseInt(counter);
    $(this).datepicker({
       // changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: $("#startdate_"+ (counter)).val(),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#startdate_"+counter).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```